# Command line arguments show 0?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, command-line, arguments

```
package commandLine;

public class commandLine {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("There are " +args.length+ " Command-line Arguments");
    System.out.println("They are: ");
    for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++){
        System.out.println("arg["+i+"]: "+args[i]);
    }

}

}
```

I wanted to check the length of my command-line arguments and loop through them to display the array of command lines. However, it says my command line arguments are 0? How can this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official Java [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) about command-line arguments.

> **Command-Line Arguments**
>
> A Java application can accept any number of arguments from the command
>   line. This allows the user to specify configuration information when
>   the application is launched.
>
> The user enters command-line arguments when invoking the application
>   and specifies them after the name of the class to be run. For example,
>   suppose a Java application called Sort sorts lines in a file. To sort
>   the data in a file named friends.txt, a user would enter:
>
> **java Sort** *friends.txt*
>
> When an application is launched, the runtime
>   system passes the command-line arguments to the application's main
>   method via an array of Strings. In the previous example, the
>   command-line arguments passed to the Sort application in an array that
>   contains a single String: "friends.txt".
>
> **Echoing Command-Line Arguments**
>
> The Echo example displays each of its command-line arguments on a line
>   by itself:
>
> ```
> public class Echo {
>   public static void main (String[] args) {
>      for (String s: args) {
>          System.out.println(s);
>      }
>   } 
> }
> ```
>
> The following example shows how a user might run Echo. User input is
>   in italics.
>
> **java Echo** *Drink Hot Java*
>
> Drink
>
> Hot
>
> Java
>
> Note that the application
>   displays each word — Drink, Hot, and Java — on a line by itself. This
>   is because the space character separates command-line arguments. To
>   have Drink, Hot, and Java interpreted as a single argument, the user
>   would join them by enclosing them within quotation marks.
>
> **java Echo** *"Drink Hot Java" Drink Hot Java*

If you are using IDE (Eclipse or etc.) you have to specify command-line arguments via some kind of run configuration. For example for [Eclipse](http://theopentutorials.com/post/uncategorized/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-in-eclipse-ide/):

[image: Eclipse]

Comment: @eli how do you start your program?

Comment: I press the play button in eclipse? I am not sure what you are asking?

Comment: @eli as you are using Eclipse, you have to specify command-line arguments via Run configurations. I edited my answer.

Comment: Awesome!Thank You Extremely helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

In have the command line is essentially of the form

java [vm options] class/jar [arguments]

Only these final arguments are given to you in the array. This is unlike a standard C program where you receive the command name also.